# pandas - how to vectorized group by calculations instead of iteration

Tags: pandas

Here is a code sniplet to simulate the problem i am facing. i am using iteration on large datasets

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'grp':np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5],500),'col1':np.arange(0,500),'col2':np.random.randint(0,10,500),'col3':np.nan})

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #based on group label, get last 3 values to calculate mean
    d=df.iloc[0:index].groupby('grp')
    try:
        dgrp_sum=d.get_group(row.grp).col2.tail(3).mean()
    except:
        dgrp_sum=999
    #after getting last 3 values of group with reference to current row reference, multiply by other rows
    df.at[index,'col3']=dgrp_sum*row.col1*row.col2
```

if i want to speed it up with vectors, how do i convert this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically calculate moving average over every group.
Which means you can group dataframe by "grp" and calculate rolling mean.
At the end you multiply columns in each row because it is not dependent on group.

```py
df["col3"] = df.groupby("grp").col2.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)  
df["col3"] = df[["col1", "col2", "col3"]].product(axis=1)
```

Note: In your code, each calculated mean is placed in the next row, thats why you probably have this `try` block.

```
# Skipping last product gives only mean
# np.random.seed(1234)
# print(df[df["grp"] == 2])
     grp  col1  col2        iter      mask
4      2     4     6  999.000000  6.000000
5      2     5     0    6.000000  3.000000
6      2     6     9    3.000000  5.000000
17     2    17     1    5.000000  3.333333
27     2    27     9    3.333333  6.333333
```

Comment: i may have oversimplify my snipplet. what if i am trying to do a scipy poisson instead with  mean of previous values?